# Get data from django database model

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-database

I have a django model, `PhoneNumberVerification`.

It has two columns: phone number, and code.
I want to be able to get the code if I am given a phone number. Essentially, search the table for which row has the phone number as my phone number, and fetch the code for that given row.

I could write SQL for this, but I do not know how to execute that to fetch data in django models, and I was wondering if there was a better non-sql way to do this.

My model:

```
class PhoneNumberVerification(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.TextField(max_length = 20, blank = False, unique = True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length = 8, blank = False)
```

What I want:

```py
from .models import PhoneNumberVerification

def get_code(phone_number):
    # do some stuff
    return code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def get_code(phone_number):
  verification = PhoneNumberVerification.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
  return verification.code
```

Django's documentation has great tutorial for beginners.
[Writing your first Django app, part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial02/)

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, and the tutorial is very good too!

Comment: Yeah. That's why I like Django: written by python, easy to integrate with machine learning models, detailed tutorial and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

to get the object, you can simply use:

```python
def get_code(phone_number):
   try:
        phone_number_verification = PhoneNumberVerification.objects.get(phone_numer=phone_number)
        code = phone_number_verification.code
        return code
    except PhoneNumberVerification.DoesNotExist:
        pass # django will raise exception in case if number does not exist
```

if you know there is only one object that matches your query, you can use the `get()`, which will return the object directly.

Otherwise, you can use `filter()`, more on that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: Thanks! but @MinhDao already solved my problem with the same solution